# The roots of equation $x3^x=1$ are

Tags: transcendental-equations

I have to find roots of equation
 $x3^x=1$

A.Infinitely many roots

B.$2$ roots

C.$1$ root

D. No roots\

How do i start? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

$$3^x = \frac{1}{x}$$ Has only $1$ solution.

Comment: Which solution??

Comment: Solution will be in first quadrant.

Comment: @SophieClad: how can you accept this solution which gives absolutely no justification ?

Comment: It is a multiple choice question and therefore most likely is meant to be solved under time pressure. The hint I gave allows OP to solve the question by using some intuition rather than a complete answer.

Comment: Ya i m also not getting it

Comment: The result can clearly be understood if you know how to sketch both functions. And why the downvote?

Comment: @YvesDaoust i accepted it because i got idea of making graphs of both sides.

Comment: @SophieClad There are true answers to the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is not a condition for accepting an answer. And how can I be downvoted for OP accepting my answer. Stop being bitter.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes you are right. But i have to sit in exam where i have to tick correct answers. I do not need such deep explanations.

Comment: I also upvoted this answer, because A) it gets the job done (the actual question is about the number of solutions), B) I somewhat dismiss Lambert W, and oppose any "political" motion of getting it included in the list of elementary functions. At least until it begins to have so many applications that it is included in standard pocket calculators and such. Mind you, I won't downvote questions/answers using W, I just ignore them.

Answer (score 4):

For a simple answer plot the graphs of $y_1=3^x$ and $y_2=\frac{1}{x}$, (that are elementary), and see that these graph intersects only at a point $x_0$ such that $0<x_0<1$  because:

1) $3^0=1$ and $ \frac{1}{x} \to +\infty$ for $x \to 0^+$

2) $y_1(1)=3^1=3>y_2(1)=\frac{1}{1}=1$

3) the two functions are continuous in $(0,1]$.

4) for $x>0$ $y_1$ is monotonic increasing and $y_2$ is monotonic decreasing and for $x<0$:  $y_1>0$ and $y_2<0$.

If you want the value of $x_0$ this cannot be done with elementary functions. You can use the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) that is defined as:
$$
W(xe^x)=x
$$
so, from
$$
x3^x=1 \iff xe^{x\ln 3}=1
$$
using $x\ln 3=t$ we find:
$$
te^t=\ln 3\quad \Rightarrow \quad t=W(\ln 3)
$$
and
$$
x_0=\frac{W(\ln 3)}{\ln 3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Define the function $f(x)= x3^x-1= x\exp(ln(3)x)-1$ and study the variation of this function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by Newton raphson method.

$x3^x=1$

By solving i got $x$ approximately equal to 0.5478

The given problem have only one solution( by graphical method )